# ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2)) when using includes() and where() in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to debug an issue in `Rails 5.1.5`, `Postgres 2.1.3`. This query works fine in my production environment, but when I copy the database locally and try to do the same thing, I get this error:

```
Author.includes(:books).where({books: {id: 1}})

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2))
```

Every other query I've tried works, and all of the data/versions I've checked seem the same. This also fails if there are no authors at all in the database.

The relationship is set up like this in the Author model

```
has_many :books, dependent: :destroy
```

I've tried dropping the database entirely, recreating it from scratch, etc.

Does anyone have any ideas where to dig in from here?

Comment: Is there a stack trace to go with that error? Are you sure that the error is caused by that line of code?

Comment: I'm running it from the rails console so I'm sure, the rest of the traceback is just

Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):3. 

It could be coming from anything in ActiveRecord etc that gets called by that line of the code, but there's nothing more in the traceback to give a hint.

Comment: First split it in two (`q = Author.includes(:books); q = q.where(...)`) and then include the stack trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Rails documentation for [`includes`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes), you'll see how it works here

```
User.includes(:posts).where('posts.name = ?', 'example')
```

So, when rails yells at you

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2))
```

It's might be expecting you to give it

```
Author.includes(:books).where("books.id = ?", 1)
```

That doesn't make a ton of sense to me (because your syntax should work), but that was the first thing that came to mind when you got the "it requires 2 params", because in older versions of Rails, that's how it worked.

Some other options might include using [`SpawnMethod#merge`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge) (my favorite):

```
Author.joins(:books).merge(Book.where(id: 1))
```

Which essentially performs a left join using ActiveRelation to combine the two queries into a single sql query.

Answer (score 2):

Is this over nested? Or do you have existing scopes?

```
Author.includes(:books).where(books: {id: 1})
```

instead of

```
Author.includes(:books).where({books: {id: 1}})
```

This is rails 5 syntax, if you are using rails 5.

Comment: Good answer. That syntax predates rails 5, by the way.

Comment: What do you mean by over nested / existing scopes? I'm running this in the Rails console with my very first command, so there's not much else going on. I tried the new syntax and it has exactly the same behavior; works on production, fails with wrong number of arguments error locally.